# Simulink: Creating a repeating irregular square wave

Tags: matlab, sequence, simulation, simulink, repeat

I want to genereate a square wave to represent different uptimes for a lightning installation over a year.

The schedule over a week is the following:
Mon-Thu: 06.00-20.00
Fri: 06.00-18.00
Sat: no uptime
Sun: no uptime

So my wave should repeat every 168 hours (one week) and look like this:

```
Time Signal  
0-6     0    
6-20    1
20-30   0
30-44   1    
44-54   0
54-68   1
68-78   0    
78-94   1
94-104  0
104-116 1    
116-168 0
```

I've tried some with the repeating sequence block using the following:

```
Time values:[0 6 6.001 20 20.001 30 30.001 44 44.001 54 54.001 68 68.001 78 78.001 94 94.001 104 104.001 116 116.001 168]
Output values: [0 repmat([0 1 1 0],1,5) 0]
```

But since I'm simulating over 8760 (a year in hours) it seems that the step is f*cking things up.

Is there any better way or good way to make this work?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Can you try creating one continuous signal with values for each hour? i.e. Create a vector with 168 values with 0 for 0-6 and 1 for 6-20 etc.

Comment: Can you please be explicit about what "f*cking things up" means.  What exactly is not working?  What error (if any) are you getting? Is the shape of the curve wrong?  Is it not repeating properly? Is the rest of your model not working with any step change in the signal?

Comment: When I use standard simulation settings with auto for max min and initial stepsize the curve it seems that the simulation takes gigantic steps so the signal only raises to the value 1 over the full simulationtime (8760).

Comment: When I decrease maxstep to 0.001 (since some values are put to eg. 6.001) it seems to plot it as I want "live" in the scope, but when it finishes there is only one peak of value 1. I get the message that suggests I should use discrete solver but the results is the same, looks fine when "live" but not when it's done.

Comment: I just realised that I forgot to uncheck the box "Only 5000 data points" history. Solved the problem!

Comment: The default (auto) max time step is the end time divided by 50, so you probably want to specify a max step size. If your model does not contain any continuous states, it makes sense to use a discrete solver. The scopes only display 5000 data points by default, you need to untick the check box, as you have found out.